# Is it safe to change title of view AllItems.aspx in Document Library?

Tags: document-library, view

I'm always extremely paranoid when it comes to renaming / changing standard "objects" like views or fields within SharePoint.

I have received a request to rename the **title** of the `AllItems.aspx`-view of a dozen document libraries.

Is it safe to change the title (**not the URL**) of that view from "All Documents" to "Folder View" for example?

Or is renaming these OTB-views violating some best practices or does it even break some internal functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem. Otherwise you could create a new View which looks the same as AllItems.aspx, set this as default view and give it your desired title.

Comment: I'd like to keep the number of views for the end user to a minimum. So cloning the view would be the second best option :)

Answer (score 2):

It is even best practice to title the (New) View first with a URL save name (without spaces) eg: AllDocuments

That way a readable URL is created: /AllDocuments.aspx (instead of /All%20Documents.aspx)

Then edit the View again and set the Title to: All Documents

So yes, it is perfectly safe to edit Titles

And it is safe to change the URL as well...

**Even if you have used Links to your ASPX page somewhere else on Pages or in WebParts 
SharePoint will update all links automagically**

Note: this only applies to content managed by SharePoint, if you use external JavaScript files with (hardcoded) Links; they will not be updated.
Unless...you put them in a Style Library where they become managed documents.

Comment: You're talking about creating a new (custom) view, aren't you? I want to rename the title of the OOTB view "AllItems.aspx" ("All Documents") that comes with every document library.  Please excuse me, if I have misunderstood your answer.

Comment: Same applies to all existing (View) pages.  I don't have code at hand; I suggest you use (search for) a Powershell script to dive into your sites and do the changes (but for some 50 sites or so it might be faster to do it by hand.. just go get 5 black coffees and go get Carpal Tunnel Syndrom in two hours). Or use TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey to trigger a automatic rename on any EditView.aspx page.